# How to change the value of a snackbar based on the value of a boolean?

Tags: angular, angular-material, snackbar

I have a registration form and i want to show a message to the user of whether he was successful or not, for this i am using a snackbar that i made as an angular component and that i open with a button in my app component, however, i want to pass the value of a boolean to the snackbar component so that based on the value it shows a different message. My code is something like this:

**app-component.html**

```
<button mat-raised-button type="submit" id="registerButton" (click)="openSnackBar()">
   <p id="registerText">Register</p>
 </button>
```

I'm using this function to open the snackbar in my app-component file:

**app.component.ts**

```
 openSnackBar(){
   this.snackbar.openFromComponent(SnackbarComponent, {
     duration: 2000,
   });
  }
```

This is my snackbar component template:
**snackbar.component.html**

```
<span class="text" matSnackBarLabel *ngIf="isRegistrationSuccessful == true; else registrationFailed">
    You have registered successfully
  </span>
  <span matSnackBarActions>
    <button mat-button matSnackBarAction (click)="snackBarRef.dismissWithAction()"></button>
  </span>

  <ng-template #registrationFailed>
    <span class="text" matSnackBarLabel>
      Failed to register
    </span>
    <span matSnackBarActions>
      <button mat-button matSnackBarAction (click)="snackBarRef.dismissWithAction()"></button>
    </span>
  </ng-template>
```

and this is what i have on my file:
**snackbar.component.ts**

```
export class SnackbarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  isRegistrationSuccessful: boolean = false;
  
  snackBarRef = inject(MatSnackBarRef);

}
```

what i want to do is set the value of `isRegistrationSuccessful` from my **app.component.ts** when i trigger the snackbar and show a different message depending of said value, which is why i'm using ng-template, however, i have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the Angular Material Doc, it looks like you can pass data to your custom snackbar via the constructor with something like this:

```
export class SnackbarComponent { 

    constructor(@Inject(MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA) public isRegistrationSuccessful: boolean) { }
}
```

I think this makes the code to call showing this component to be something like this:

```
openSnackBar() {
  // assuming you have some way to get whether registration was successful
  let result = this.someRegistrationService.getRegistrationResult();

  this.snackbar.openFromComponent(SnackbarComponent, {
    isRegistrationSuccessful: result,
  });
}
```

https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what i needed, thank you very much.